# Preg match all characters for array items

Tags: php, arrays, pdf

I have an array that lists folder names

```
$excludes=array("phpMailer","pdf");
```

and i want to match all other directories and files within the listed directories

for example, using the above array i want to make the $excludes array be

```
phpMailer/other-dir/file1.php
phpMailer/other-dir/file2.php
phpMailer/dir2/dir3/file10.php
pdf/file1.php
pdf/dir6/phpfile.php
pdf/folder/dir2/file11.php
```

and so on... for everything listed in the array

i thought maybe using `preg_match('/./', $excludes);` would do it but it didn't

Comment: second parametr for preg_match is a string

Comment: do you have an example? and that hasn't really answered my question

Comment: what @tttpapi is saying is you can't pass an array to `preg_match()` in the second param, it needs to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/./', $excludes)
```

'/./' means whatever but with length = 1. You should probably change it to

```
preg_match('/.*/', $excludes); // which means whatever nevertheless how long it is
```

Comment: ok thank you - will this match all directories and files for the directory names in my array?

Comment: No, it will not. This 'preg_match('/.*/', $excludes);' will check if there is any string in $excludes. And $excludes cannot be an array!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a cycle.

```
$excludes = array("phpMailer","pdf");

foreach ($excludes as $exclude) {
  if (preg_match($exclude, $fileNameAndPath)) { //$fileNameAndPath - your current file with a complete path
    //CODE to exclude...
  }
}
```